# Replacing expression

Tags: replacement

My goal is to make expression simpler using Replace funcion with the assumption; $$ (1+x)^n  \approx  1+n x  $$
The expression at the nominator was replaced as expected, but the expression in the denominator could not be replaced.  My code is as below. Where should I have to modify?

```
((-1 + Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2])*\[Sigma])/
     (2*Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2]*
        \[Epsilon]0) //. 
   Sqrt[1 + (a_)^2/(h_)^2] -> 
     1 + a^2/(2*h^2)
```

[image]

Comment: `expression /. (1 + z_)^n_ -> 1 + n z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have similar problems, always look at the full form of your expression:

```
((-1 + Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2])*\[Sigma])/(2*Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2]*\[Epsilon]0) // FullForm
```

[image]

Note that the Sqrt in the denominator is written:

[image]

with an exponent of -1/2. Therefore, this does not match the pattern Sqrt[...]. You must use, as it has been proposed, a pattern with an undefined exponent: (1 + z_)^n_

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
expr = ((-1 + Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2])*\[Sigma])/(2*
     Sqrt[1 + a^2/h^2]*\[Epsilon]0);
Series[expr, {a, 0, 2}] // Normal

(*  (a^2 \[Sigma])/(4 h^2 \[Epsilon]0)  *)
```

Have fun!